# How to read in data from a csv file and insert the data into an html file

Tags: javascript, python, html, csv

I'm trying to create a Python script that will (a) read a csv file with data, (b) take that data and insert it into specific tags of an html string, (c) and finally write that modified html string to an html file.

So far, I have the script to read in from a csv file here:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row

f.close()
```

I also have the script that will write an html file here:

```
import webbrowser

# open blank file
f = open('template.html', 'w')

message = """<style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">h1.page-title { display: none; }</style>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        <div class="twoblocks">
            <div class="blocks-holder grey">

                <div class="block-left w50 bkgimage" style="background-image: url('/images/common/not_pictured-wide.jpg');">
                    <div class="force-16x9">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>

                <div class="block-right w50 content" style="width: 50%;">
                <h1>Dr. Rosen Rosen</h1>
                <span class="superhead">Title, <a href="index.php?Itemid=XXXX">Department</a></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Biography</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam hendrerit mauris dictum metus porta, in consectetur dui aliquam. Nunc eu pharetra ipsum. Donec nec tincidunt dolor. Mauris dolor nisi, pellentesque quis tellus malesuada, placerat tristique dui. Phasellus at dui in nunc vestibulum accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis non interdum ipsum, et tristique leo. Pellentesque condimentum, felis id placerat placerat, purus purus mattis urna, ac sodales ipsum ipsum ut risus. Aenean eget molestie ante, nec blandit magna. Integer efficitur fringilla odio sit amet sagittis. Sed ante turpis, pulvinar condimentum vehicula ac, tempus cursus ante. Donec eu scelerisque metus. Vestibulum facilisis tincidunt fermentum. Phasellus consequat odio in libero pharetra rutrum.</p>

        <hr />

        <h3>Education</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>Ph.D., Field of Degree, University of Lorem Ipusm, 1990</li>
            <li>M.S., Field of Degree, University of Lorem Ipusm, 1990</li>
            <li>B.S., Field of Degree, University of Lorem Ipusm, 1990</li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <h3>Classes Taught</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - First Class</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Second Class</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Third Class</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="classes" class="collapse">

            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced top-0">
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Fourth Class</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Fifth Class</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Sixth Class</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default expand collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#classes"></button>

        <hr />

        <h3>Affiliations</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>Organization</li>
            <li>Organization</li>
            <li>Organization</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="affiliations" class="collapse">

            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced top-0">
                <li>Organization</li>
                <li>Organization</li>
                <li>Organization</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default expand collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#affiliations"></button>

        <hr />

        <h3>Publications</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
            <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
            <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="publications" class="collapse">

            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced top-0">
                <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
                <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
                <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default expand collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#publications"></button>

    </div>

    <aside class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="well">

            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <p>Address <br />Building Name <br />Room # <br />City, State, Zip <br /> <a href="/map"><i class="ico-map"></i>Map</a></p>
            <p><i class="ico-phone"></i> XXX.XXX.XXXX <br /> <a href="mailto:">name@example.com</a></p>
        </div>

        <h3>Academic Interests</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>Area</li>
            <li>Another Area</li>
            <li>Area</li>
            <li>Another Area</li>
        </ul>

    </aside>

</div>"""

# write to file
f.write(message)

# close file
f.close()

# open in browser
filename = 'file:////Scripts/' + 'template.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
```

So as of now, I can read in information from a csv file, and I can also create an html file with the template I'm using. Where I'm stuck, is how to take that csv information and stick that information into the html in a specific order in the tags.

For example, each row in the csv has the information to fill out the html template. Basically, the first column contains the 'name' for the `<h1>Dr. Rosen Rosen</h1>`, the next column has the 'title' for `<span class="superhead">Title,`, and so on down through the html.

This script is basically allowing me to use a csv with a bunch of information and build a webpage so that I don't have to continually go into the code and manually enter it. I'm just having a problem figuring out how to get this script to do what I want it to do since I'm relatively new to Python.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I think you're asking how to enter data into an HTML webpage, the fact that it's from a CSV is irrelevant I think. Look into something like Jinja2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine your scripts into one script. For each row in the csv file you extract the data for that doctor then you use string concatenation to splice it with the ginormous html string. Then you write that string to the output file.

Below is a sample that outputs the name, title, and department data.

However, I have to agree with @TankorSmash that this may not be the best solution. Some kind of [templating engine](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) is usually easier to work with.

```
import webbrowser
import csv

# open blank file
f = open('template.html', 'w')


with open('./data.csv', 'r') as c:
    reader = csv.reader(c)
    for row in reader:
        name = row[0]
        title = row[1]
        department = row[2]

        message = """<style scoped="scoped" type="text/css">h1.page-title { display: none; }</style>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9">
        <div class="twoblocks">
            <div class="blocks-holder grey">

                <div class="block-left w50 bkgimage" style="background-image: url('/images/common/not_pictured-wide.jpg');">
                    <div class="force-16x9">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>

                <div class="block-right w50 content" style="width: 50%;">
                <h1>""" + name + """</h1>
                <span class="superhead">""" + title + """, <a href="index.php?Itemid=XXXX">""" + department + """</a></span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <h3>Biography</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam hendrerit mauris dictum metus porta, in consectetur dui aliquam. Nunc eu pharetra ipsum. Donec nec tincidunt dolor. Mauris dolor nisi, pellentesque quis tellus malesuada, placerat tristique dui. Phasellus at dui in nunc vestibulum accumsan. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis non interdum ipsum, et tristique leo. Pellentesque condimentum, felis id placerat placerat, purus purus mattis urna, ac sodales ipsum ipsum ut risus. Aenean eget molestie ante, nec blandit magna. Integer efficitur fringilla odio sit amet sagittis. Sed ante turpis, pulvinar condimentum vehicula ac, tempus cursus ante. Donec eu scelerisque metus. Vestibulum facilisis tincidunt fermentum. Phasellus consequat odio in libero pharetra rutrum.</p>

        <hr />

        <h3>Education</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>Ph.D., Field of Degree, University of Lorem Ipusm, 1990</li>
            <li>M.S., Field of Degree, University of Lorem Ipusm, 1990</li>
            <li>B.S., Field of Degree, University of Lorem Ipusm, 1990</li>
        </ul>

        <hr />

        <h3>Classes Taught</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - First Class</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Second Class</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Third Class</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="classes" class="collapse">

            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced top-0">
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Fourth Class</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Fifth Class</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://catalog.example.com/search/?search=CLA+###">CLA ### - Sixth Class</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default expand collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#classes"></button>

        <hr />

        <h3>Affiliations</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>Organization</li>
            <li>Organization</li>
            <li>Organization</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="affiliations" class="collapse">

            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced top-0">
                <li>Organization</li>
                <li>Organization</li>
                <li>Organization</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default expand collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#affiliations"></button>

        <hr />

        <h3>Publications</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
            <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
            <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
        </ul>

        <div id="publications" class="collapse">

            <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced top-0">
                <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
                <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
                <li>"Article Title." <em>Name of Publication.</em> Volume, Page Numbers. Authors (Date).</li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default expand collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#publications"></button>

    </div>

    <aside class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="well">

            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <p>Address <br />Building Name <br />Room # <br />City, State, Zip <br /> <a href="/map"><i class="ico-map"></i>Map</a></p>
            <p><i class="ico-phone"></i> XXX.XXX.XXXX <br /> <a href="mailto:">name@example.com</a></p>
        </div>

        <h3>Academic Interests</h3>
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-spaced">
            <li>Area</li>
            <li>Another Area</li>
            <li>Area</li>
            <li>Another Area</li>
        </ul>

    </aside>

</div>"""

        # write to file
        f.write(message)

# close file
f.close()

# open in browser
filename = 'template.html'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
```